# PHP switch statement not saving states when using $variable and if statements within switch options

Tags: php, if-statement, switch-statement

I am using a switch statement to delete/update records and sort the table. I wish to set up the application to save the sort even as a different switch option is selected. Right now I can sort the data, but when I click to delete a data element the data set reverts to the original unsorted form. I have attempted to save the state with $state and if statements in the other switches. If I remove the if statement and leave a function it works fine, however the if statements are needed to select the specific last state the system was in. What is incorrect here?

```
$TPL[‘displayTable’] = true;
$TPL[‘updateTable’] = false;
$TPL["fetchedrecord"] = [];
$state = 0;

switch ($_REQUEST["act"]) { 

  case "updatestart":
    $recordid = $_REQUEST["id"];
    $TPL["fetchedrecord"] = fetchRecord($conn, $recordid);
          $TPL[‘displayTable’] = false;
          $TPL[‘updateTable’] = true;


  break;

  // updating a record from the database 
  case "update":

    updateRecord($conn,
            $_REQUEST["id"],
            $_REQUEST["fnameUP"],
            $_REQUEST["lnameUP"],
            $_REQUEST["phoneUP"],
            $_REQUEST["emailUP"],
            $_REQUEST["locationUP"],
            $_REQUEST["mcUP"],
            $_REQUEST["posUP"],
            $_REQUEST["deptUP"]);
          $TPL[‘displayTable’] = true;
          $TPL[‘updateTable’] = false;

    if($state==1){
    $TPL["phonebook"] = sortDataLName($conn); 
    }
    if($state==2){
    $TPL["phonebook"] = sortDataPosition($conn);  
    }
    if($state==3){
    $TPL["phonebook"] = sortDataDepartment($conn); 
    }
    else{
    $TPL["phonebook"] = getAllData($conn);
    }

    break;

  // deleting a record from the database 
  case "delete":

    $recordid = $_REQUEST["id"];
    deleteRecord($conn, $recordid);
    if($state==1){
    $TPL["phonebook"] = sortDataLName($conn); 
    }
    if($state==2){
    $TPL["phonebook"] = sortDataPosition($conn);  
    }
    if($state==3){
    $TPL["phonebook"] = sortDataDepartment($conn); 
    }
    else{
    $TPL["phonebook"] = getAllData($conn);
    } 

    break;


  // sorting records by last nae 
  case "sortname":
    $state = 1; //state is sort name
    $TPL["phonebook"] = sortDataLName($conn);  
    break;

  case "sortposition":
    $state = 2; //state is sort position
    $TPL["phonebook"] = sortDataPosition($conn);  
    break;

  case "sortdepartment":
    $state = 3; //state is sort department
    $TPL["phonebook"] = sortDataDepartment($conn);
    break;

  // insert a new record into the database  
  case "insert":

    insertRecord($conn,
              $_REQUEST["fname"],
              $_REQUEST["lname"],
                  $_REQUEST["phone"],
                  $_REQUEST["email"],
            $_REQUEST["location"],
            $_REQUEST["mc"],
            $_REQUEST["pos"],
            $_REQUEST["dept"]);
    if($state==1){
    $TPL["phonebook"] = sortDataLName($conn); 
    }
    if($state==2){
    $TPL["phonebook"] = sortDataPosition($conn);  
    }
    if($state==3){
    $TPL["phonebook"] = sortDataDepartment($conn); 
    }
    else{
    $TPL["phonebook"] = getAllData($conn);
    }

    break;

  default:  
     $TPL["phonebook"] = getAllData($conn);

}
```

Comment: I'm surprised that the quote marks around `displayTable` and `updateTable` don't throw syntax errors.

Comment: think you need to store the changes either in a file or database or session

Comment: @Leo, yes I just tried session_start(); and saving the states there and no luck

Comment: better try with saving to a file, much easier to see if it works. Session might be turned off or not configured

Comment: for example `$req = file('test.txt'); $id = isset($_REQUEST['id']) ? $_REQUEST['id'] : $req[0];`

Comment: I am unfamiliar with this answer, could you please detail it?

Comment: make a variable to save $_REQUESTs then save it to a file in the end of the script, and open file at the start. so everytime script loads it reads the config from a file. Also if a new request is sent, it should overwrite the variable.

Comment: Oh i see. Okay. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

basic example of logic
just to see if it works, for different users you might want to use a database with different users having different configs or a session..

```
<?php
//some $data
$data[] = 1;
$data[] = 3;
$data[] = 2;
//read $config from file
if(file_exists('test.txt'))
{
$config = file('test.txt');
$config['state'] = $config[0];
unset($config[0]);
}
//catch REQUEST
if(isset($_REQUEST['state']))$config['state'] = $_REQUEST['state'];
//sort if request is 1
if($config['state'] == 1)
    sort($data);
//output $data
print_r($data);
//save config to file
file_put_contents('test.txt', implode(PHP_EOL, $config));
```

for sessions better read a manual or https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp